# Using Thread Sleep in an application to Control a motor - Is there a better alternate

Tags: c#, windows, thread-sleep

All,

FYI:
C# .net app running on Windows controlling a piece of hardware (DC motor) via I/O board

I have a program that controls a DC motor. I create a dedicated (higher priority) thread (to control the rotation of the motor independently of the running application).

Based on a specific running use-case, the program issues the motor a command that includes angular position information when to stop motor rotation (technically, the dedicated motor thread receives the position, wakes up, energizes the motor, and then monitors the motor progress until the desired position is reached).

**Question:**

The dedicated motor thread uses Thread.Sleep(30ms) function to wait for the hardware to:

-Energize the motor

-Start moving the motor in a direction

-Allow some time to make some progress based on the speed of the motor (before checking for desired end condition, ie has the motor reached desired position?)

Since the CPU runs at 4.7GHz, you want some time to elapse before doing any logic for checking if the motor reached its desired position.

Is there a better a way of doing this other than Thread.Sleep()?
I really don't care that much about precise timing or the lack of it because Sleep() doesn't give you that but more interested in having smooth operation of the motor and as close to real-time checking as possible on Windows to see if the motor reached desired position.

Comment: Windows is not a real-time operating system, and x86 is not a real-time processor. I think you've simply picked the wrong machine for the job.

Comment: @Charlieface I know that. I don't need 100% accurate control of the motor. Also, current implementation works quite well with some precision artifacts (That probably relate to lack of real-time control). In addition, the software communicates with another software that runs on x86, Windows, so it has to be Windows app. It is for gaming, not anything else.

Comment: Windows is good enough for basic control, as long as you're OK with a little slop in timing and you're not running a ton of other stuff on the machine. If the OS starts paging, all bets are off. You probably also probably want to _pre-jit_ your code so that the _JITter_ doesn't get in the way, and try to get your app loaded into memory before you start _controlling_ things.There are a ton of control systems that run on x86 Windows (though, admittedly, not using managed code). The thing about Thread.Sleep is that it sleeps the thread; that thread is dead for 30ms. You may want to look at async.

Comment: You may also want to read up on [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=net-7.0). If you process starts a GC during that 30ms, bad things will happen

Comment: @Charlieface: what do you mean about x86 not being a _real-time processor_. Is it missing some feature(s). I've worked for several companies that based there (complex) control systems on x86, some on Windows, some not

Comment: I worked for a company that built a controller on x86 with a rt Linux that controlled a linear motor of a 1 metric ton stone table moving with accelerations of up to 10m/s^2 ... And it worked just fine. So, I really don't think the platform is a problem. OS and language _may be_.

Comment: Windows does not work well with multiprocessing unless you using async methods.  You do not need to use a sleep.  Instead you need to use interrupts (timer events) and you need to block you code so program does not exit.  I would eliminate your loops in your code with sleep and instead block the code from exiting with a WaitOne : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-7.0  The sleep in the example code is not needed if you use a timer to do your processing.

Comment: @Flydog57 I suppose it is possible to use x86 for this kind of thing, but you'd need a very well written operating system that you could rely on for exact timing. Proper systems would normally use a robotics PLC such as Siemens Simatic.

Comment: Lots of great suggestions, thanks. It is hard to convey my implementation without sharing the entire code. I do use interrupt like logic using a pair of Event objects for signaling (ie, the dedicate motor thread lies dormant until it is signaled through an event). The thread sleep() is there just a poor man's hardware delay. Using WaitHandle would be probably a better solution but now that I think about it, but not sure if I really want a context switch. It might be better just to spin on multi core system. Timer is probably best solution but I would have to re-design the whole control logic.

Comment: Look up how to use `async` and `await` (Stephen Cleary's blog is the best source: start here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). Expose your naturally asynchronous native programming as async methods. Use `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` while you are in critical control regions of your code. Work to reduce JIT-induced pauses, and try to get your whole program paged in before you start controlling things. Use an async mindset (like `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: I know how to use async await, I use it every day in my day to day job. The motor controller application is just a hobby project. The app was designed/written 15 years ago when these constructs did not exist. It was done via the traditional spawn your thread approach. To employ the new constructs might be difficult (since async propagates and you don't want to mix async with schronous code). In addition, async/await uses thread pool and a thread scheduler which gives less control when the actual task is performed. I prefer to be in control of thread scheduling as much as possible.

Comment: If you hunt around, there is/are additional thread pool classes out on the internet.  I used them once where I needed to have two very distinct thread types (for quick work and slow work), but wanted to get thread-pool-like behaviour